# Can I use log4j in a web app with a file other than log4j.xml or log4j.properties?

Tags: java, web-applications, logging, log4j

Is it possible to use something other than the file names log4j.xml or log4j.properties to configure log4j logging in a Java web application?

I want to load a log4j.xml file from a different location on the file path (not in my classpath). Is that possible in a web application using say, JBoss or Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PropertyConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).Call `configure` with file you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Dlog4j.configuration=path/to/your/file.xml` startup parameter to specify where your configuration file is. It's the recommended practice anyway:

> The preferred way to specify the default initialization file is
>   through the log4j.configuration system property.

([log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html))